# How do you prevent buttons from merging into each other with the .btn-group class in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When using the .btn-group class in bootstrap, how do you keep a column of buttons from collapsing into another column? In this example, the right column collapse into the middle column when reducing page width. Is there another class I should be using to prevent this? JsFiddle with live example is below.

Desktop Screen Size:
[image]

Smaller Screen Size:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="industry_center_button">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_left">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button pull-right ">AdTech</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">B2B</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_right ">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button"><span class="industry_button_multiline">Consumer Electronics</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_left">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button pull-right "><span class="industry_button_multiline">Digital Media</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">eCommerce</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_right ">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button"><span class="industry_button">Employent</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_left">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button pull-right ">Ed Tech</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button"><span class="industry_button_overflow">Entertainment</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_right ">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">Fashion</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_left">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button pull-right ">Fin Tech</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">Fitness</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_right ">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">Gaming</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_left">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button pull-right "><span class="industry_button_multiline">Internet of Things</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">Media</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_right ">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button"><span class="industry_button_multiline">Non-profit</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_left">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button pull-right ">Other</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button"><span class="industry_button_multiline">Public Relations</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_right ">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">Publishing</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_left">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button pull-right "><span class="industry_button_multiline">Real Estate</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">Security</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_right ">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">Software</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_left">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button pull-right "><span class="industry_button_multiline">Travel &amp; Hospitality</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button">Wearables</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 industry_button_padding industry_button_right ">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-default industry_button" style="visibility: hidden;"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.industry_button {
    font-size: 10pt;
    width: 98px;
    height: 41px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.industry_button_multiline {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 7px;
}
.industry_button_overflow {
    position: relative;
    right: 12px;
}
.industry_button_padding {
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.industry_button_left {
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
}
.industry_button_right {
    position: relative;
    right: 25px;
}
.industry_center_button {
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
}
.btn-group {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4gy7w8ta/) with the live example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your `.industry_button_right` and `.industry_center_button` classes that are causing them to overlap. You have `width: 30%;` set for `.industry_center_button` which limits the column width/space for the buttons on smaller screens along with `right: 25px;` set for `.industry_button_right` that nudges the third button to the right of where it naturally wants to position itself.